# Exception - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Label not found in Mahout

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, classification, mahout

I am running the following commands,

```
/mahout trainnb 
    -i ${WORK_DIR}/20news-train-vectors -el 
    -o ${WORK_DIR}/model 
    -li ${WORK_DIR}/labelindex 
    -ow

./mahout testnb 
    -i ${WORK_DIR}/20news-test-vectors
    -m ${WORK_DIR}/model 
    -l ${WORK_DIR}/labelindex\
    -ow -o ${WORK_DIR}/20news-testing
```

On running the last command,I am able to run the map task to 100% but on reduce task I am getting the the following Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Label not found: 10002
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:88)
        at org.apache.mahout.classifier.ConfusionMatrix.getCount(ConfusionMatrix.java:182)
        at org.apache.mahout.classifier.ConfusionMatrix.incrementCount(ConfusionMatrix.java:                205)
        at org.apache.mahout.classifier.ConfusionMatrix.incrementCount(ConfusionMatrix.java:                209)
        at org.apache.mahout.classifier.ConfusionMatrix.addInstance(ConfusionMatrix.java:173                )
        at org.apache.mahout.classifier.ResultAnalyzer.addInstance(ResultAnalyzer.java:70)
        at org.apache.mahout.classifier.naivebayes.test.TestNaiveBayesDriver.analyzeResults(                TestNaiveBayesDriver.java:160)
        at org.apache.mahout.classifier.naivebayes.test.TestNaiveBayesDriver.run(TestNaiveBa                yesDriver.java:125)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.mahout.classifier.naivebayes.test.TestNaiveBayesDriver.main(TestNaiveB                ayesDriver.java:66)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java                :43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java                :72)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:144)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:152)
        at org.apache.mahout.driver.MahoutDriver.main(MahoutDriver.java:195)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java                :43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

I am following the example from http://www.packtpub.com/article/implementing-the-na%C3%AFve-bayes-classifier-in-mahout and also tried the seqdumper on labelindex and can see the keys and values in it.

I am using Hadoop 2.2,Mahout 1.0 and whole environment is setup on Amazon EC2.

Please help me out.Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I think mahout is not compatible with your hadoop version, you should download the 1.1.0 or 1.2.0 versions of hadoop.
this will probabely fix your problem.

Comment: Can you explain why you think this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have your files in local. I also had this problem and I fixed it when I changed the files to HDFS